# Find number of terms when natural numbers occur in separate terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

How many terms are in the series

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,........,20,....twenty times 20...., 20
```

I tried a few things- the most promising way I found is by taking the above as:

```
1, 4, 9,...., 20^2
```

where nth term is n^2, thinking somehow later I could add up the number of terms which I combined and reduced by forming another special series but I couldn't figure it out.

This is actually number of rounds of running a block I want to go for each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum of $n$ first terms is
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

There are $$1+2+...+(20) $$terms in the series..So put $n=20$ in above formula

$$20(21)/2=210$$ So there are $210$ terms in total

Comment: Please read the question again. I specifically mentioned- Separate terms. I have tried finding the sum of n^2 terms and then adding the terms I missed.

Comment: Oh yes. That didn't strike me.